# Compare values across two sheets, highlight similarities, Runs but doesnt work

Tags: vba, excel, highlight, string-comparison

OK so I am doing a bank rec, I have one worksheet ("Deposits and Credits"), the bank statement, which I am comparing to an internally created report ("June PB INS").

For each item in the bank statement, I am searching in the internal report for a row that has matching date (column 1), contains the company descriptor (string1), and matches the amount (column 3 in the bank statement, column 2 OR column 15 in the internal report).

If there is a match I want to highlight the row in the bank statement worksheet and I want to mark in column 7 the address of the internal report row that matches.

the Code seemingly has no flaws but doesn't make any of the changes.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub HighlightMatches()
Dim Sht1LastRow As Long, Sht2LastRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim iPBINS As Long, iPBINScount As Long, iDeposits As Long, iDepositscount As Long
Dim string1 As Variant

Sht1LastRow = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(10000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sht2LastRow = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
iPBINS = 2
iDeposits = 2

For iDeposits = 2 To Sht1LastRow
string1 = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 7).Value
    For iPBINS = 2 To Sht2LastRow
        If Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) Or Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15) Then
            Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 12).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Address(1, 1, 1, 1) And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows("iDeposits:iDeposits").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .Color = 5296274
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
        End If
    Next iPBINS
Next iDeposits

End Sub
```

Comment: How many records do you have? More than 10000 and your method of finding the last row will fail (meaning you never enter the loops). Prefer something like `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: The Sht1LastRow and Sht2LastRow both get the proper values, the row number with the last entry of the sheet. the Internal report has 70k records and Sht2LastRow, when hovered over in debug mode, displays the correct number of the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding parenthesis will make your `If` statement work.

```
If (Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2)) Or (Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15)) Then

End If
```

There is no need to repeat the conditions the `If` statement just group the `Or` conditions together and enclose them in parenthesis.

```
If Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 And (Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) Or Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15)) Then

End If
```

I would prefer to break the `If` statement into two statements to make it more readable.

```
If Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) <> 0 Then
    If Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) Or Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3) = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15) Then

    End If
End If
```

You shouldn't concatenate lines of code like this:

`Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 12).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Address(1, 1, 1, 1) And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows("iDeposits:iDeposits").Select`

Incorrect:

`Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows("iDeposits:iDeposits").Select`

Correct:

`Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows(iDeposits & ":" & iDeposits").Select`

---

I would prefer to shorten the variable names.  Like this:

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Dim wsPB As Worksheet

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim x2 As Long, x2count As Long, x1 As Long, x1count As Long

    Set wsPB = Sheets("June PB INS")
    With Sheets("Deposits And Credits")

        For x1 = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            For x2 = 2 To wsPB.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If .Cells(x1, 1).Value = wsPB.Cells(x2, 1).Value And InStr(1, wsPB.Cells(x2, 3).Value, .Cells(x1, 7).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

                    If .Cells(x1, 3) = wsPB.Cells(x2, 2) Or .Cells(x1, 3) = wsPB.Cells(x2, 15) Then

                        .Cells(x1, 12).Value = wsPB.Cells(x2, 1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
                        With .Rows(x1).Interior
                            .Pattern = xlSolid
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .Color = 5296274
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                        End With

                    End If
                End If
            Next x2
        Next x1

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this as a template and then used Tim's If statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute variables for the long sheet.cell.value references, you'll find your error (and see that you are making extraneous comparisons)

```
Dim TransDate As String
Dim TransAmt As Long
Dim PBINSDate As String
Dim PBINSAmt As Long

TransDate = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 1).Value
PBINSDate = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Value
TransAmt = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 3).Value

    If TransDate = PBINSDate _
    And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) > 0 _
    And TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) _
    Or TransDate = PBINSDate _
    And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) > 0 _
    And TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15) _
    Then
        Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(iDeposits, 12).Value = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 1).Address(1, 1, 1, 1) And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows("iDeposits:iDeposits").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5296274
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
    End If
```

We really don't need to search the same string for the same value twice: `InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) > 0` We also don't need to check if the dates match more than once: `TransDate = PBINSDate' Let's get rid of the extras and see what it looks like.

```
    If TransDate = PBINSDate _ 
    And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) > 0 _
    And TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) _
    And TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15) _
    Then
```

Going back to your criteria and fixing the `AND`s and `OR`s:

```
    'The Dates must match
    If TransDate = PBINSDate _
    'The descriptor must be found in the statement line item
    And InStr(1, Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 3).Value, string1, 1) > 0 _
    'The statement amount should match either column 2 OR column 15
    And (TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 2) _
         Or _
         TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(iPBINS, 15) _
    ) _
    Then
```

Another issues I'll point out:

InStr returns the starting position of the needle in the haystack or 0 if its not found. Thus, `Instr("abcde","c",1)` retruns `3`. When using this as a logical operator, you only need to check if the value is greater than 0.

Comment: Nice breakdown +1.  I liked how you used variables make the `If`statement  more readable.  You missed `Rows("iDeposits:iDeposits")`.   The `Instr() <> 0` is common practice.  I sure that it wouldn't any difference here but I read somewhere that `<>` evaluates faster then using `>`.

Comment: I like descriptive variable names. It makes reading my spaghetti code so much easier 5 months from now. :) Interesting note about `>` vs `<>`. I tried to test it by looping through a 50 million element array of random characters, but `Now` doesn't offer enough granularity and 5 billion crashed my PC. Not that nanoscale efficiency is a primary feature sought by VBA developers... I meant to mention the concatenation issues after the If...Then, but my boss thinks I should do real work sometimes.

Comment: Lol..bosses really get in the way.  I wish I knew where I read about `<>` versus `>`.  You can use `Timer` to measure millisecond.  The basic pattern is `Dim Start : Start = Timer : 'Do Something : Debug.Print "Execution Time:"; Timer - Start`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code I ended up with, Decided to ditch the match string portion

```
Sub StackCombined()

Dim TransDate As String
Dim TransAmt As Long
Dim PBINSDate As String
Dim PBINSAmt As Long

Dim wsPB As Worksheet
Dim Sht1LastRow As Long, Sht2LastRow As Long
Dim x2 As Long, x2count As Long, x1 As Long, x1count As Long
' Sht1LastRow finds the last row of Deposits and Credits with a value
Sht1LastRow = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(10000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Sht2LastRow finds the last row of June PB INS with a value
Sht2LastRow = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(100000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Call worksheet June PB INS just wsPB
Set wsPB = Sheets("June PB INS")
With Sheets("Deposits And Credits")

    For x1 = 2 To Sht1LastRow

        For x2 = 2 To Sht2LastRow
            'TransDate is the transaction date recorded from the bank
            TransDate = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(x1, 1).Value
            'PBINSDate is the transaction date recorded internally through EPIC
            PBINSDate = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 1).Value
            'TransAmt is the bank statements amount of the transaction
            TransAmt = Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Cells(x1, 3).Value

                'The Dates must match
                'The amount must either column 2, single record, OR column 15, daily record
                'if these two conditions are met, highlight the bank statement and record where the match was found
                If TransDate = PBINSDate _
                And (TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 2) _
                    Or _
                    TransAmt = Sheets("June PB INS").Cells(x2, 15) _
                ) _
                Then
                    .Cells(x1, 12).Value = wsPB.Cells(x2, 1).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) And Sheets("Deposits And Credits").Rows(x1 & ":" & x1).Select
                       With Selection.Interior
                          .Pattern = xlSolid
                          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                          .Color = 5296274
                          .TintAndShade = 0
                          .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                      End With
               End If
        Next x2
    Next x1
End With
End Sub
```